# How to Backup/Restore TRAINS-server when moving from AMI to local machine

Tags: kubernetes, deep-learning, trains, clearml

I recently started using TRAINS, with the server in AWS AMI. We are currently using v0.9.0.

I would like to move the TRAINS-server to run on our on-premises kubernetes cluster. However, I don't want to lose the data on the current server in AWS (experiments, models, logins, etc...).
Is there a way to backup the current server and restore it to the local server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this package is quite new, I'm making sure we are both referring to the same one, *TRAINS-server* https://github.com/allegroai/trains-server (which I'm one of the maintainers)

Backup the persistent data folders in the *TRAINS-server* AMI distribution:

- MongoDB: /opt/trains/data/mongo/
- ElasticSearch: /opt/trains/data/elastic/
- File Server: /mnt/fileserver/

Once you have your Kubernetes cluster up, restore the three folders to a *sharable location*. When creating the *TRAINS-server* deployment yaml make sure you map the *sharable location* to the specific locations the container expects, e.g. /mnt/shared/trains/data/mongo:/opt/trains/data/mongo

Start the Kubernetes *TRAINS-server*, it should now have all the previous data/users etc.

Comment: This will be the exact same process, in order to upgrade the *TRAINS-server* to the next version.

Comment: Glad, it worked. Just a quick etiquette fyi, I'm a member of the TRAINS team :)